# placeholder "search forms" shows up when run html from c: location on my computer, but not copy of html on a server

Tags: html

For some reason, the placeholder, "search forms", shows up when I run the html from c: location on my computer, but not copy of html on a server. This is using the same browser.  When I searched online, it said it was the version of IE, but it can't be that since I'm viewing in the same browser for both html's.

```
<div style="float: center;">
<h1>Required Document Forms </h1>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms.." title="Type in a name">
   <h2>Initial Appointment Forms</h2>
   <h3>General Initial Forms:</h3>
   <li><a href="\\server\Documents\Initial Forms\General Initial Forms\Background Check.pdf" target="_app">Background Check</a></li>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Any ideas? Could the extranet show different things than the intranet?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any errors when running your code. Can you provide some information to reproduce the problem?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="float: center;">
<h1>Required Document Forms </h1>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms.." title="Type in a name">
   <h2>Initial Appointment Forms</h2>
   <h3>General Initial Forms:</h3>
   <li><a href="\\server\Documents\Initial Forms\General Initial Forms\Background Check.pdf" target="_app">Background Check</a></li>
</div>
```